# Manipulate html tags with django template

Tags: django, django-templates

On my page I showing feeds from 3-rt party pages and for showing the article I remove all unnetsesery html tags by using `removetags:"b br span a table tbody tr td div strong"` but some of article have img tag, I like to keep this but I like to add extra information to this tag like `itemprop="image"`.
Is any way that allow to me "inject" itemprop="image" to ready predefined `<img alt="title of image" src="http://example.com/media/k2/items/cache/b2bfbef5bf07350b746434a35b46d416_L.jpg" />` ?

for example my query for article in template:

```
<div class="media-body">
  <span itemprop="articleSection">{{ object.content|removetags:"b br span a table tbody tr td div strong"|safe|truncatewords_html:56 }}
  </span>
</div>
```

gives me following:

```
<div class="media-body">
<span itemprop="articleSection">
<p>
<img class="attachment-full wp-post-image" width="256" height="256" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/tt.jpg" alt="tt">
(example.nl) – w końcu zaplanowano rozbudowę lotniska w Eindhoven. Przedsięwzięcie będzie realizowane etapami, tak aby w 2020..............
</p>
<p>Het bericht Dodatkowe loty z lotniska w Eindhoven verscheen eerst op Popolsku.</p>
</span>
</div>
```

How to add extra attribute `itemprop="image"` to img tag

Answer (score 0):

If you explain your concrete issue, showing some code or giving some more information, I could show you a solution with Django, but we can explore other solutions.

Let's say we have this image file:

```
<img id="image_id" alt="whatever" src="http://something" />
```

## JQuery

Via JQuery you can add an attribute to an existing element using `.attr()`, in this case we could do:

```
$('#image_id').attr('itemprop','image')
```

## JavaScript

In JavaScript we have `.setAttribute()`

```
document.getElementById("question-header").setAttribute('itemprop', 'image')
```

and in both ways the image will ends like:

```
<img itemid="image_id" alt="whatever" src="http://something" itemprop="image"/>
```

---

To do something like this with Django I would say you should create your own template tag, I could show something in Django with more information.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I updated question with more details